# I have a problem to start my dhcp server in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, dhcp

There are my configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
// The installation is successfull
nano /etc/network/interfaces
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.21.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.21.0
   gateway 192.168.21.254
nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
   authoritative;
   ddns-update-style none;
   default-lease-time 240;
   max-lease-time 380;
   subnet 192.168.21.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.21.30 192.168.21.70
   option routers 192.168.21.1}
```

When i write "service isc-dhcp-server start" in "/etc/init.d", i have this error: "start: job failed to start"
PLEASE HELP ME!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're missing semicolons inside of your subnet declaration.  Try:

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
authoritative;
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 240;
max-lease-time 380;
subnet 192.168.21.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.21.30 192.168.21.70;
  option routers 192.168.21.1;
}
```